# Does it matter if we put time consuming operations in @Transactional methods?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, transactions

My question relates to the fact that I don't understand very well how transactions work in JPA.

Let's say I have a service and a repository: I will make all the methods from the service `@Transactional`, but consider the following scenario:

In my service I have a method `persistData` that looks like the following:

```
@Transactional
public void persistData(){
    make an http request which is slow or any other time consuming method
    repository.persistData(...)
}
```

Will Hibernate open a transaction and keep it for nothing until this method returns or it will just issue the transaction when I call the persist on the objects and thus the SQL will execute?

Comment: Hibernate will not process this `@Transactional` annotation because it is nothing to do with JPA API. Your container will process it ... whether JavaEE or Spring. Similarly this "repository" is nothing to do with the JPA API; most likely that is Spring also

Comment: ok, but does it matter i do hard work in it or not?

Comment: why don't you just try it and see what you think? This site is not for "opinion-based" questions, and this is an opinion-based question.

Comment: This is not an opinion based question at all! How on earth am I suppose to test this? My concern is if it's resource wasting for the database or not.